# Where Can Deutsche Bank Stock Opinions Be Found?

Tags: stocks, stock-analysis

I have been looking for Deutsche Bank stock opinions with little success. All I could find was on [finviz.com](http://www.finviz.com) where If I search for a stock it will mention if Deutsche Bank has an opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Stocks(equities) aren't rated. They only get opinions from ananlysts, typically "sell", "buy", "hold", etc. Companies are **rated** for their debt instruments, i.e. bonds.

[Here are some ratings for Deutchse Bank](http://www.db.com/ir/en/content/ratings.htm). Ratings are best obtained from the major rating agencies, such as Standard & Poor's, Moody's, and a few others, but they may not be free. Browse the company's website for whom you want to check the ratings.

Comment: @JoeHobbit - Edited the answer.

Comment: http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=MX (ctrl+f then type "Deutsche Bank") Whatever that thing is called - a "buy" rating on a stock.

Comment: I am not interested in debt ratings.

Comment: @JoeHobbit - Those are analyst opinions as I mentioned. Those opinions are varied and issued by multiple agencies. Traders, banks etc. You cannot get all buy or sell or hold or outperform ratings. That is one's own opinions. You cannot get a collated opinion. You have to visit that specific opinion givers and check why they are giving the same opinion. Check out FT or cnnmoney or WSJ for such opinions.

Comment: Many brokerages will also provide you with tools to research the analysts' ratings of a stock, if you are a customer. See, for example, ETrade's sample reports: https://us.etrade.com/investing-trading/independent-investment-research?ploc=it-nav The Motley Fool - http://fool.com - also will have information about Wall Street analysts' coverage and their own employees' and community members' opinions. You should take all these opinions with a grain of salt, naturally. :)